# Strip HTML elements within DIV

Tags: javascript, html, strip-tags

I have a simple search engine on one of our older websites. This site is running IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003. The search functionality is provided by Microsoft Indexing Service.

You can see the search functionality on our [website](https://www.termpro.com/dbdrag/rules/2020/rules.asp?Org_ID=1&Format_ID=1&Section=99). (Just type in "speakers" and you will see some hits.

I would like to use the "FullHit" feature offered by the indexing service. When using this feature the Indexing service inserts the full hit results in between "begindetail" and "enddetail" on a target web page.

The problem that I have is that the documents that are being returned have HTML. This looks messy. (Just click on "Hit Locator Tool" in the search results above to see what I mean.)

I would like to create a DIV section such as ...

```
<DIV name="target">

     begindetail

     enddetail

 </DIV>
```

Then, after the page is populated I would like to use javascript to strip out all of the HTML elements (but not the data) between the opening and closing DIV.

For example, `<FONT color="magenta">Good Data</FONT>` would be modified to only show `Good Data`.

I can also use Classic ASP if necessary.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or know of any functions that I can add to the target page to accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you remove all tags, you will also get cases where line breaks disappear, possibly putting lots of text on one line.

Answer (score 1):

I inspected your webpage, and there definitely must be some logic errors in your ASP code. (1) Instead of something like `<div></div>` being passed to the browser, it is HTML entities for special characters, so it is being passed like `&ltDIV&gt &lt/DIV&gt`, which is very ugly and is why it is rendering as text instead of HTML code. In your ASP code, you must not be parsing the search result text before passing it to the browser. (2) All of this improperly-formatted code is inserted after the first closing `html` tag, and then there are closing `body` and `html` tags after the improperly-formatted code, so somewhere in your ASP code, you are telling it to append the code to the end of the document, rather than insert it inside the original `<body></body>`.

If you want to decode the mixture of HTML entities, `<br>` tags, and text into rendered HTML, this JavaScript may work:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var text = decodeHTMLEntities(document.body.innerText);
    document.write(text);
}

function decodeHTMLEntities(text) {
    var entities = [
        ['amp', '&'],
        ['apos', '\''],
        ['#x27', '\''],
        ['#x2F', '/'],
        ['#39', '\''],
        ['#47', '/'],
        ['lt', '<'],
        ['gt', '>'],
        ['nbsp', ' '],
        ['quot', '"']
    ];

    for (var i = 0, max = entities.length; i < max; ++i) 
        text = text.replace(new RegExp('&'+entities[i][0]+';', 'g'), entities[i][1]);

    return text;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6ohc1tkr/

But **first things first**, you need to fix your ASP code, or whatever you use to parse and then display the search results. That's what is causing the improper formatting and display of the HTML. Show us your back-end code and then we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was use TXT files (with no HTML, HEAD, or BODY tags) as Include File documents for the Table of Contents ASP page. By converting the TXT document to a standard HTML page it fixed the problem. I will go back in and change the Include File to Inline Links.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to accomplish what you are trying to do.

> [string-strip-html](https://gitlab.com/codsen/codsen/tree/master/packages/string-strip-html)

It worked pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I now have the search feature working as expected. I would like to thank everyone for their insightful comments. This feedback helped me identify and fix the problem.

OS: Windows Server 2003
IIS: 6.0
Microsoft Index Server

The hit locator tool will only work properly for HTML pages. If you use this tool with a simple TXT file then the results will not be displayed correctly.